# scalacheck: Generate a non empty string

Tags: scala, scalacheck

What is the best way to generate a non empty string, when in the context of something like this

```
  private def createIndexFn() = {
      for{
        someChar <-  Gen.alphaString
        aNumber <- Gen.choose(1,100)
        //...
       }       
       yield { 
           MyThing(AnotherType(someChar.toString), SomeOtherType(aNumber), aNumber)
   }
 }
```

where you need maybe someChar to be a non empty string. I know you can use `whenever` in the `forAll` section but I wonder how to do it in this part of the generator.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The accepted answer caused a high ratio of discarded tests for me, I ended up using:

```
import org.scalacheck._

Arbitrary(Gen.nonEmptyListOf[Char](Arbitrary.arbChar.arbitrary)).map(_.mkString))
```

Answer (score 13):

What I was looking for was:

```
import org.scalacheck.Arbitrary.arbitrary

arbitrary[String].suchThat(!_.isEmpty)
```

and can be used like

```
for {
  name <- arbitrary[String].suchThat(!_.isEmpty)
  age  <- Gen.choose(0, 100)
} yield Person(name, age)
```

Hopefully this helps someone

Comment: It could help more if you add the imports required to make it compiles ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a fix length random string

```scala
Gen.listOfN(10, Gen.asciiPrintableChar).map(_.mkString)
```

or to create a random length with a constrained length

```scala
for {
  n     <- Gen.chooseNum(5, 20)
  chars <- Gen.listOfN(n, Gen.asciiPrintableChar)
} yield chars.mkString
```